# How to solve the requested URL /rest was not found on this server while running Opsview's REST API?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, opsview

I installed Opsview using [this guide](http://docs.opsview.com/doku.php?id=opsview-core:centos-installation). The problem is that REST API does not work.

Executing:

```
/usr/local/nagios/bin/opsview_rest --username=admin \
--password=password GET config/host
```

results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The
requested URL /rest was not found on this server.</p> <hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Goto undefined subroutine &Carp::shortmess_real at
/usr/share/perl5/Carp.pm line 41.
```

I assume that the issue was caused by some Apache settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not mention this in the documentation but REST API should **always** point at the actual web port of Opsview.

Changing `localhost` by adding Opsview's default web port to `localhost:3000` in **/usr/local/nagios/bin/opsview_rest** solved the issue.